# Multiplying column by value returns "not a single-group group function" error

Tags: sql, oracle, multiplication

I have created a table which records the number 3_point_attempts and 3_points_scored in basketball for a single match.

What I would like to do is multiple the values of 3_point_attempts*1.5 and 3_point_scored*3 however when doing so I receive a "not a single-group group function" error.

Please check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1123d/2) dbfiddle

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please read about aggregate functions. They all require Group By...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum() over()` to get the result:

```
SELECT performanceid, 
  matchid, 
  teamid, 
  twopattempts, 
  (SUM(twopattempts) over(partition by teamid))*2  AS SumPoints
FROM Performance
WHERE TeamID = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1123d/16)

If you want to add the three point attempts, then you can use:

```
SELECT performanceid, 
  matchid, 
  teamid, 
  twopattempts, 
  SUM(twopattempts) over(partition by teamid)*2  AS SumPoints,
  sum(THREEPATTEMPTS) over(partition by teamid)*1.5 as ThreePointAttempts,
  sum(THREEPSCORED) over(partition by teamid)*3 as ThreePointScored
FROM Performance
WHERE TeamID = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1123d/18)

The above will give you the total values on each row returned.  If you want it based on `matchid` and `teamid`, then you could use:

```
SELECT MatchID,
  teamid, 
  SUM(twopattempts)*2  AS SumPoints,
  sum(THREEPATTEMPTS)*1.5 as ThreePointAttempts,
  sum(THREEPSCORED)*3 as ThreePointScored
FROM Performance
WHERE TeamID = 1
group by teamid, MatchID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1123d/21)

Comment: In regards to the last snippet where it groups by teams I have altered the SQL for the desired results but it also returns an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1123d/31. The error is caused by me trying to add together the agregated columns.

Comment: @Imran you cannot use the alias names in the `total` column you will have to use the formula again -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1123d/34 You will also have to group by `FTSCORED` if it is not in an aggregate function

Comment: Because FTSCORED is not aggregated and grouped the results of the query are not as desired. It generates more than 2 records. What can I do to get around this?

Comment: @Imran you might be able to `sum(distinct ftscored)` -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1123d/46

Answer (score 1):

Do the multiplication directly:

```
SELECT performanceid, matchid, teamid, twopattempts, twopattempts*2 AS SumPoints,
        3_point_attempts*1.5, 3_point_scored*3 
FROM Performance
WHERE TeamID = 1
```

You only need the `group by` when you are trying to aggregate rows.  For instance:

```
select teamid, sum(3_point_attempts*1.5), sum(3_point_scored*3_
from Performance
group by TeamID
```